# "[: s: integer expression expected" error in Bash script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

This Bash script produces multiple "integer expression expected" errors when run:

```bsh
echo "Enter string"
read str
len=`echo $str|wc -c`
len=`expr $len - 1`
i=0
j=1
l=`expr $len / 2`
while [ $i -le $l ]
do
start=`echo $str|cut -c $j`
end=`echo $str|cut -c $len`
echo $start
echo $end
if [ $start -ne $end ]
then 
echo "not palindrome"
exit 0
fi
len=`expr $len - 1`
i=`expr $i + 1`
j=`expr $j + 1`
done
echo "string is palindrome"
```

This is the output, including errors:

```
Enter string                                                                                                                  

saurabh                                                                                                                       
s                                                                                                                             
h                                                                                                                             
main.bash: line 18: [: s: integer expression expected                                                                         
a                
b                                                                                                                             
main.bash: line 18: [: a: integer expression expected                                                                         
u                                                                                                                             
a                                                                                                                             
main.bash: line 18: [: u: integer expression expected                                                                         
r
r                                                                                                                             
main.bash: line 18: [: r: integer expression expected                                                                         
string is palindrome
```

What is wrong in the script?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using external commands like `wc`, `expr`, `cut`, you can and should use [bash internal string manipulation](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) commands. Also, your script is suited to use [bash arithmetic operations](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ops.html).

So, I have revised your script as shown below. See also my comments in the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter a string > "
read str
#len=`echo $str|wc -c`
#len=`expr $len - 1`
# You could use just `echo -n ...` and skipped the subtraction.
# But, for a better alternative use this:
let len=${#str}
let i=0
let j=1
#l=`expr $len / 2`
let l=len/2
while (( i < l )) ; do
  #start=`echo $str|cut -c $j`
  start=${str:j-1:1}
  #end=`echo $str|cut -c $len`
  end=${str:len-1:1}
  echo "$start" '=?' "$end"
  if [[ "$start" != "$end" ]] ; then 
    echo "Not a palindrome"
    exit 0
  fi
  #len=`expr $len - 1`
  let len=len-1
  #i=`expr $i + 1`
  let i++
  #j=`expr $j + 1`
  let j++
done
echo "String is a palindrome"
```

This script can still be optimized a bit further. This is left as an exercise for you! ☺

Please, note that if you are using non-ASCII characters in your test string, the appropriate locale should be set. For example:

```
$ LANG=C.UTF-8 ./pal.sh 
Enter string > ΝΙΨΟΝΑΝΟΜΗΜΑΤΑΜΗΜΟΝΑΝΟΨΙΝ
Ν =? Ν
Ι =? Ι
Ψ =? Ψ
Ο =? Ο
Ν =? Ν
Α =? Α
Ν =? Ν
Ο =? Ο
Μ =? Μ
Η =? Η
Μ =? Μ
Α =? Α
String is a palindrome
$ LANG=C ./pal.sh 
Enter string > ΝΙΨΟΝΑΝΟΜΗΜΑΤΑΜΗΜΟΝΑΝΟΨΙΝ
� =? �
Not a palindrome
```